# How to customise android dialogs to material theme?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I wanted to customise android Dialog to make it look like a floating dialog as below which is suggested in https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-simple-dialogs [image]

I tried creating a DialogFragment in which onCreateDialog returns a Dialog with a view whose root is a CardView.But couldn't get the expected result.Can I have some suggestions on how to achieve this?

My layout looks like this,

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
  //Contents come here
  
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and in code,

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_font_selection,null,false);

        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(view);
        float width = (I am getting screen width here) * .80f;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout((int) width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        return dialog;
    }`
```

but the result looks like this,
Instead of getting elevation I was getting a black shade 
[image]

Comment: post your code for more understanding

Comment: @MohitMadaan edited the question

Comment: What device are you running on?

Comment: Running on a Jellybean device

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder mydialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( context);
mydialog.setTitle("Set backup accounts");
mydialog.setItems(CharSequence[] items, OnClickListener);
mydialog.show();
mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialogLayout);
```

This in your activity/fragment. And so declare your layout as follow:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/myID1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After that, if you want to handle the clicks just do that:

```
TextView myView1 = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(myID1);
myView1.setOnClickListener(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I tried this but got something like a dialog which has an elevation effect but have a white shade(some few pixels wide) around it

Comment: so change to: mydialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( context )
...
mydialog.setContentView(R.style.MyAlertDialoh); // be sure to call this after the .show() method

Comment: Thanks..How can the method setContentView take a style resource..Did you mean the same?

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: Since the layout is wrapped at root level ..just a dialog with a transparent background with textviews(texts added)

Comment: Ok so: add a wrapping <RelativeLayout> containing all my code, set width&height to match_parent and set its background with "#99999999". This will create a fullscreen size layout with a semi-trasparent gray background

Answer (score 0):

`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` is now available for Android:

[material.io/develop/android/components/dialog](https://material.io/develop/android/components/dialog/)